# "Unexpected error" thrown when using UrlFetch

Tags: google-apps-script, double-click-advertising

I have been using App Scripts to Download and insert CM360 reports into Google Sheets for a while now, but since a couple of days back I get the following error when running the code:

> Exception: Unexpected error: https://www.googleapis.com/dfareporting/v3.4/reports/xxx/files/xxx?alt=media (Code:23:56)

Example of the code I am running:

```
function runreport() {
var reportId = xxx;
var profileId = xxx;
var additionalParameters = {'synchronous': 'true'};

var ReportFile = DoubleClickCampaigns.Reports.Files.list(profileId,reportId);
var ReportFileID = (ReportFile.items[0].id);
var newReportFile = DoubleClickCampaigns.Files.get(reportId, ReportFileID);

if(newReportFile.urls) {var httpOptions = {'headers': {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(newReportFile.urls.apiUrl, httpOptions).getContentText();
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);}}
```

Do anyone else encountered this issue and have managed to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "When looking into the URL"?

Comment: This URL: https://www.googleapis.com/dfareporting/v3.4/reports/xxx/files/xxx?alt=media that is pushed form the response in App Scripts. However, I realise now that the response from just that URL, when inserted into a browser, will provide a auth error since I have not inserted the header/auth into the call.

Comment: @AR Yes, So the 401 is irrelevant and  the only part relevant is the "Unexpected error"

Comment: You might wanna [edit] the question to reflect that. Also, this is better addressed by Google. Create a issue in the issuetracker and add the link to the issue here as a answer. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question and will create an issue in the issuetracker! Thanks!

Comment: This question was undeleted as the answer is useful and significant efforts were made by others, who contributed. If you don't want to be associated with this question, you can [flag] your own question for moderator intervention to remove your name from this question.

Answer (score 2):

### The `unexpected error` is due to a new bug with `UrlFetchApp`

It has already been filed serveral times, e.g. [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/175141974).

So instead of filing it again you should rather "star" the already existing issue - to increase its visibility.